# Проблема при установке intl в php 7.4

Tags: php, openserver

Использую OpenServer Panel
В php.ini выглядит вот так:

```
extension_dir                = "c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP_7.4/ext"


;extension = intl
```

При попытке раскоментировать, при перезагрузке сервера, обратно комментируется.
php_intl.dll установлен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно раскоменчивать в правильных местах. На выбор одно из двух мест:

Первое место - это через меню OS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второе место в папке `\userdata\config\ТУТ_НУЖНЫЙ_PHP_ФАЙЛ`